# Android: File path for Pictures on 4.x

Tags: android, mono, camera, xamarin.android

(Java or C# answers are fine, I use Mono)

I am calling the Camera intent:

```
var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file));                
StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Where `_file` is:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/crime/mypic.jpg
```

The path is retrieved via:

```
var dir = new Java.IO.File(
       Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
           (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "crime");
```

However, `the root of this path does not exist on my device` (/mnt) and when the camera app loads, I can only press Cancel, not Done.

I think there is problem with the path.

`The question is` , is there a better way to get the path and is that why the Done button in the Camera app does nothing?

Comment: If `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is returning an invalid value, your device has buggy firmware. How are you determining that `/mnt` does not exist?

Comment: I have just found that using DirectoryDcim instead of DirectoryPictures solves the problem. Perhaps a MonoDroid issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DirectoryDcim` instead of `DirectoryPictures` solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully Google will index these strings for Xamarin Android Camera directory path

"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/".

which can be reached via symlink

/sdcard/DCIM/

which is ultimately

/mnt/shell/emulated/0/DCIM/

I've searched for days before arriving here.